# Forming a String in java

Tags: java, string

I need to form a String in java like this

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "match (n:Person) return n limit 20",
      "resultDataContents": [
        "row",
        "graph"
      ],
      "includeStats": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to from the above string using variables in java I have done this till now

```
String query = "match (n:Person) return n limit 20";

"{\"statements\" : [ {\"statement\" : \"" + query +  "\"} ]}"
```

How can I append the remaining string as shown above Please assist.

Comment: Why don't you use a library like GSON which generates and parses JSON for you? It makes your life easier beacuse you do not make mistakes like forgotten commas at the end of a line.

Comment: Formatting this can be a pain in the ass, just use a JSON library like Jackson, JSON P or GSON. Also I think Java has some built-in JSON classes, check out JsonObject.

Comment: as @Hidde mentioned, don't invent the wheel

Comment: There's only one correct answer here, and Hidde and dabadaba have already given it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the java string

```
String strFinalString=
"{\"statements\": [{\"statement\": \"match (n:Person) return n limit 20\",\"resultDataContents\": [\"row\",\"graph\"],\"includeStats\": true}]}";
```

with variables, try

```
String strStatementsStart="{\"statements\": [";
String strStatementsEnd="]}";

String strStatementStart="{\"statement\": ";
String query="\"match (n:Person) return n limit 20\"";
String strStatementEnd="}";

String strResultDataContents="\"resultDataContents\": ";
String strResultDataContentsValue="[\"row\",\"graph\"]";

String strIncludeStats="\"includeStats\": ";
String strIncludeStatsValue="true";

String strFinalString=strStatementsStart+strStatementStart+query+","+strResultDataContents+strResultDataContentsValue+","+strIncludeStats+strIncludeStatsValue+strStatementEnd+strStatementsEnd;
```